# Is it true that $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y \to 0}f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x,x)$?

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Is it true that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y \to 0}f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x,x)?$$

I have no idea how to disprove or prove it, but it seems intuitively like it must be true.

Comment: I don't think so. You are talkin about two different variables.

Comment: But do you mean the limit $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Consider this counter example:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{y^2}{xy}=\lim_{x\to 0}0=0$$
while $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1.$$

Comment: Ah so it is not true intuitively because in the first case tbeelimit is first taken w.r.t. 1 variable, and then w.r.t the second when the value of  the first limit is already inserted into the formula, whereas in the second case the limits are basiclly taken "at the same time"

Comment: Right, in general limits don't commute.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not true because you talking about two different variables because if you consider the function
$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy-xy^2}{x-y}$$
then you see that $$\lim{x\to 0}\lim{y\to 0}f(x,y)$$ gives defined value if you want to replace x with y then function is not defined 
So it may be true in few cases but not in general